# button_to with :remote=>true doesn't update the vote count on my page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Vote button in my view. When this button is clicked, it has to increment votes for the particular video.

In my View, I have:

```
<%= button_to 'Vote',  :method => :add_point, :remote=>true %>
```

In my controller I have,

```
@video=Video.find(params[:id])
@video.increment!(:votes)
```

But when button is clicked, votes value remains same.What is the issue in this code?

**Update:** Now, I'm getting the following error:  `Couldn't find Video without an ID` `app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:8:in`add_point'`

Comment: What is `:votes`? Is it integer column inside `videos` table or maybe this is an association?

Comment: yes votes is an integer column

Comment: Votes value remains same after reload of page?

Comment: Yes I populated DB using following seed: `Video.create(:title=>'Justin Beiber',
    :img=>'/images/capture.jpg',
    :vidurl=>'http://tinyurl.com/6ezwweo
',
    :votes=>300
)`

Comment: what will return button if you'll turn off :remote => true. And you can debug your AJAX request via Firebug. Also show your routes

Comment: When remote=>true is removed, votes value is still not incremented.For the Routes, I just uncommented the default Route.

Comment: I have the Video and Vote button in a hidden Div.This Div is loaded into a popup(using pirobox).When i click vote, the popup closes, but votes value remains unchanged

Comment: From your error: are you using inherited_resources or cancan? Please post your controller code from the controller that is throwing the error.  Your `routes.rb` file will probably help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your valuable feedback.I have tested a non Ajax version and it is working.Only thing is, Iam using default Route.Ajaxing it and adding a Route should be easy enough....or atleast i hope it is.
Here's the controller:

```
def increment
        number=Digit.find(params[:id])
        number.increment!(:value)
        #number.update_attribute(:value,"value+1")
        redirect_to(:action=>'index')
    end
```

and here's the view:

```
<%=button_to '+1',:action=>:increment,:id=>number.id%>
```

Associating this voting logic with videos or any other content should not be much effort. :)

Answer (score 5):

instead of `method` you should use `action`. Also check what method you should use with this action (in your routes.rb)

```
<%= button_to 'Vote', :action => :add_point, :remote=>true %>
```

Comment: This seems pretty plausible for why the asker's code isn't working.  It's important to note the distinction between method and action: `action` is the url you are pointing at, `method` is one of the four HTTP Methods that are you using on that url (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).  Both of these need to be correct for your form to submit to the right place.

Comment: Brett, so should i say `:action=>:add_point,:method=>POST`? I'll try it

Comment: `:action=>:add_point,:method=> :post` if it is really `post` one

Comment: @santu101 Well, I believe POST is the default so you probably don't need it *if your route is a POST route*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that the action is being completed. Go to your project directory and do:

```
tail -f log/*.log
```

Then click the button again while watching your console. If you see some UPDATE sql on your 'videos' table, then you're halfway there.

Secondly, did you write some JS in a view to respond to the Ajax request? Rather than truncate something extremely important, checkout this railscast on Unobtrusive Javascript:

Video:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Text:
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript